# Drupal pagination count issue while i try to filter the data

Tags: drupal-7

```
$table_sort = $query->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header);    
$pager = $table_sort->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($pagerLimit); 
$result = $pager->execute();
```

I use this code for pagination,everything is fine until i'm using filter option.
Page navigation link is visible even i have only one records which has come from filter by id.

```
For example:
By default i have 100 records in table,so we can see page navigation link,its good.
```

The problem is when i try to filter the records by id alone.
I got only one record which is matched for given id but still now the pagination link is visible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve readability next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countQuery = $query;
$result = $query->execute();
$Totalcount = $result->rowCount();
$page = pager_default_initialize($Totalcount,$pagerLimit);
```